# Check dependency of the job

Tags: slurm

I have set a chain of batch jobs with dependencies with SLURM.

To test if they are set correctly, I want to see which job is dependent on which job. Is there a way to check that?

By calling `squeue -u $USER` I can only see that it says `(Dependency)`, but I want to know which job they are specifically dependent on. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can inquire the dependency of jobs by specifying `%E` in the format. E.g., to check the dependency of job `$N`:

```
squeue -j $N --format "%E"
```

To check the dependency of all jobs of user `$USER`:

```
squeue -u $USER --format "%i %j %E"
```

Check the [man page of squeue](https://slurm.schedmd.com/squeue.html) for more options for `--format`.

Comment: you  meant ```squeue -u $USER --format "%i %j %E"``` right? It worked thanks a lot.

Comment: @CTN yes, thanks for pointing out the typo.